# Grails, Geb, Selenium w/ Chrome: Unable to Connect?

Tags: grails, selenium-webdriver, geb

## Problem

My selenium functional test is failing when I run using the Chrome driver, but works when using Firefox.

### My Environment

1. Mac OS X Mountain Lion
2. Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94
3. Build info: version: '2.2.1', revision: '16551', time: '2012-04-11 21:42:35'
4. System info: os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.8.2', java.version: '1.6.0_35'
   Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver

### Steps to Reproduce

The exception occurs when using the [Geb Grails example application from github](https://github.com/geb/geb-example-grails).

Run the application using the Chrome driver:

```
grails -Dgeb.env=chrome test-app
```

The tests will begin to run, an instance of Chrome is successfully opened, but nothing happens afterwards.  The Chrome browser isn't directed to a url, it just sits there with a silly grin on its face.  The below error is thrown in the console after a 15 second (or so) timeout.

### The Error

```
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Unable to either launch or connect to Chrome. 
Please check that ChromeDriver is up-to-date. Using Chrome binary 
at: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

### My Debugging Steps

1. Per [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314038/cannot-connect-to-chrome-on-selenium-mountain-lion), I've attempted various different versions of the driver with no effect.
2. The tests are successful when using the Firefox driver (sadly, I must test with Chrome).
3. Attempt to use the latest beta of chrome `Version 23.0.1271.40 beta`.  no luck.
4. Upgraded the geb and selenium versions in the test app to latest and greatest: `def gebVersion = "0.7.2" def seleniumVersion = "2.25.0"`

### Humble Thanks Section

Thanks for taking a look at this.  I'd love to adopt geb, but its been an uphill battle to date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Might be a silly answer but did you install the chrome driver? http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

For Firefox, you don't need to install a driver but for Chrome and IE, you do. That may be why your tests are running using FF and not chrome.

Good luck!

Comment: Silly as it may be, you were right....tell your sister you were riiiight.  Sweet jayzuss, I can't believe I missed that. A simple call to `brew install chromedriver` and all was well.  I _did_ have a version of chromedriver installed, but I think it was an old, out of date one.  Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: It was confusing to me as well at the beginning, that's why I thought of this possibility. Glad it solved your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is Geb related, I think you will get the similar behaviour when you run the tests using WebDriver Chrome Driver.

I have seen these kind of errors when Chrome is not on the path.
chrome.binary should always be the absolute path to the actual executable. for mac, this usually look like:
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

What version of Selenium/WebDriver you are using?

Comment: Nice idea.  I edited my path to include the Google Chrome directory: `type "Google Chrome"            
Google Chrome is /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`, but without any change in the above behaviour.